# Performing operations on custom data types?

Tags: haskell, types

I have the following data type:

```
data Users = Height Int | Age Int
```

I then have a list of ages:

```
myList = [Age 44, Age 54, Age 21, Age 34, Age 22]
```

Which I want to apply to this function:

```
myFunction :: [Users] -> [Users]
myFunction li = [x + 1 | x <- li]
```

However this causes the following error:

```
"No instance for (Num Users) arising from a use of ‘+’"
```

How can I make this work? Do I need to separate 'Age' from each of the values?

Comment: First off: what does it mean to add `1` to a `Users`? What result do you expect?

Comment: @Rhymoid I want to add 1 to the value, i.e Age 44 become Age 45

Comment: @barbrac A `User` can be a `Height`, not only an `Age`. You must specify what happens to `(x :: User) + 1` if it is either `Height` or `Age`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, the error message tells you that you are using the `(+)` function on `Users`, for which it is not defined.

So you could make `Users` an instance of `Num`, meaning that you also need to define `(-)`, `(*)`, `negate`,.. for `Users`, which seems odd.

Maybe you need something like this:

```
data User = User {height :: Int, age :: Int } deriving (Show)

addToHeight :: Int -> User -> User
addToHeight x (User h a) = User (h+x) a
```

then use:

```
let users = [User 180 20, User 185 22]
fmap (addToHeight 1) users
```

--

to leave semantics aside:

```
plus :: Int -> Users -> Users
plus x (Age a) = Age (a+x)
plus x (Height h) = Height (h+x)
```

Comment: For the purposes of this answer, `data User = User Int Int` would be simpler. You aren't making any use of record syntax.

Comment: Yes. I used it as a kind of documentation. `data Users = Height Int | Age Int` seems semantically not right and `User Int Int` a bit to generic.

Answer (score 2):

In your case I think you don't really want a new data type

```
data Users = Height Int | Age Int
```

[Type synonyms](https://wiki.haskell.org/Type_synonym) should suffice; they will work nicely with standard operators:

```
type Age = Int
type Height = Int

myList :: [Age]
myList = [44, 54, 21, 34, 22]

myFunction :: [Age] -> [Age]
myFunction li = [x + 1 | x <- li]
```

Answer (score 1):

@Schoon is right.

But if you want to make it on *your way* you can do this:

`data Users = Height Int | Age Int deriving (Show)` you have to "derive" show ;)

then:

```
older :: Users -> Users
older (Age a) = Age (a+1)
older _       = error "not Age" --Now it's better ;)
```

and your function:

```
everyOneOlder :: [Users] -> [Users]
everyOneOlder li = [older x | x <- li]
```

And then, you become this:

```
*Main> :l test.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> let x = Age 5
*Main> x
Age 5
*Main> let y = older x
*Main> y
Age 6
*Main> let z = [Age 1, Age 2]    
*Main> everyOneOlder z
[Age 2,Age 3]
*Main>
```

Nice, isn't it? :)

Comment: Use `:set -W` in ghci and you'll see that the pattern matching in `older` is not complete. And adding the Height case in older doesn't make sense semantically.

Comment: I know, I just wanted to give an answer as he wanted. Of course, the pattern matching in older isn't complete and adding the height case doesn't make sense, but it's how he wanted to do it. Now he can see, how it works, even if that's not the best practice. If I did it, I would do it differently.

Answer (score -1):

I've found the best solution using Applicative Functors.

Code:

```
data Users a = Height a | Age a deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

myList = [Age 44, Age 65, Age 21, Age 87]

instance Functor Users where
   fmap f (Age a) = Age (f a)
   fmap f (Height a) = Height (f a)

instance Applicative Users where
   pure a = (Age a)
   (<*>) (Age a) = fmap a
   pure a = (Height a)
   (<*>) (Height a) = fmap a

main = do
   let increaseAgesByOne = pure (\x -> pure (+1) <*> x) <*> myList
   print $ increaseAgesByOne
```

Output:

```
[Age 45, Age 66, Age 22, Age 88]
```

Hope this helps anyone with a similar problem.

Comment: May I ask you if you are really sure that this is what you want?

Comment: @Schoon how so?

Comment: it doesn't seem to compile . . `Conflicting definitions for ‘pure’`

Comment: and why did you add a type variable to Users. Height "Foo" is now a legal term. Shouldn't Height always be an `Int`?

Comment: @Schoon, you're using a newer version of GHC, which causes the `pure` conflict. I'm still quite convinced your answer is correct and this one is lousy.